# Sequence number bug in CouchDB 2 or is there another way to compare sequence numbers?

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-2.0

I’m digging deeper into CouchDB 2 and I’m finding some unexpected ordering with sequence numbers. In one case, I found that an early change in a _changes feed has the sequence number

```
99-g1AAAAI-eJyd0EsOgjAQBuAGiI-dN9C9LmrBwqzkJtrSNkgQV6z1JnoTvYneBEvbhA0aMU1mkj6-_NMSITTJfYFm2anOcsFT10mpTzyG-LxpmiL32eqoN8aEAcWE9dz_jPCFrnzrHGQchiFM4kSgaV0JqQ6VFF-AtAV2DggMgCEGxrNhQfatc3bOyDiKUalg2EBVoCu66KapazcUh41e69-GssjNIvcWWRokk2oNofwj0MNazy4QFURhGQ0J9LKI-SHPIBHEgiak51nxBhxnrRk
```

The last sequence number in my _changes feed, for the same DB, is

```
228-g1AAAAJFeJyd0EkOgjAUBuAGTJCdN9AjlIKFruQm2jFAEFes9SZ6E72J3gQ7JW7QCGnyXtLhy-vfAgCWVSjAip96XglW-o5afRJQwNbDMDRVSOuj3ogQJRgiOnL_O8I2urKdd4B1KCRpkRcCxH0npKo7KX4ApQH2HogsAElOKOPTBjkY5-yd2DqKYqnItA91C13BRTdNXY0VWouRrV7JDOvmrLuxlLW4VAlJ5Qzr4aznJ2wskIIy-y9sh7wcYoMKLJKRXOACjTxr3uHcsBE
```

In a browser console, the following is false

```
'228-g1AAAAJFeJyd0EkOgjAUBuAGTJCdN9AjlIKFruQm2jFAEFes9SZ6E72J3gQ7JW7QCGnyXtLhy-vfAgCWVSjAip96XglW-o5afRJQwNbDMDRVSOuj3ogQJRgiOnL_O8I2urKdd4B1KCRpkRcCxH0npKo7KX4ApQH2HogsAElOKOPTBjkY5-yd2DqKYqnItA91C13BRTdNXY0VWouRrV7JDOvmrLuxlLW4VAlJ5Qzr4aznJ2wskIIy-y9sh7wcYoMKLJKRXOACjTxr3uHcsBE' > '99-g1AAAAI-eJyd0EsOgjAQBuAGiI-dN9C9LmrBwqzkJtrSNkgQV6z1JnoTvYneBEvbhA0aMU1mkj6-_NMSITTJfYFm2anOcsFT10mpTzyG-LxpmiL32eqoN8aEAcWE9dz_jPCFrnzrHGQchiFM4kSgaV0JqQ6VFF-AtAV2DggMgCEGxrNhQfatc3bOyDiKUalg2EBVoCu66KapazcUh41e69-GssjNIvcWWRokk2oNofwj0MNazy4QFURhGQ0J9LKI-SHPIBHEgiak51nxBhxnrRk'
```

Is this a bug or do I need to use some other method to compare sequence numbers?

In looking at the other sequence numbers in my _changes feed, it looks like they are generally ordered as I would expect, but in this case it appears that when the first number, e.g. 99, jumps from 2 digits to 3 digits, the ordering breaks. If you boil this down to a simple string comparison example, you can see that '228' > '99' => false

Comment: That's always how numbers sort when you sort them alphanumerically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following answer contains excerpts from an email thread with @rnewson. I hope it helps someone else to understand sequence numbers in CouchDB 2. Thanks, Robert!

**The background:**

> There's no easy way to compare them in 2.0 and no requirement for them
>   to be in order. They are not, in short, designed to be examined or
>   compared outside of couchdb; treat them opaquely.
>
> The number on the front is the sum of the individual update sequences
>   encoded in the second part and exists only to trick older versions of
>   the couchdb replicator into making checkpoints.
>
> The latter half of the sequence string is an encoded list of {node,
>   range, seq} tuples (where seq is the integer value you know from
>   pre-2.0 releases). When a sequence string is passed back in, as the
>   since= parameter, couchdb decodes this string and passes the
>   appropriate integer seq value to the individual shard.
>
> All that said, in general the front number should increase. The full
>   strings themselves are not comparable, since there's no defined order
>   to the encoded list (so two strings could be generated that are
>   encoded differently but decode to the same list of tuples, just in a
>   different order).
>
> Another aspect to this is that the changes feed is not totally
>   ordered. For a given shard it *is* totally ordered (a shard being
>   identical to a pre 2.0 database with an integer sequence), couchdb
>   doesn't shuffle that output (though correctness of replication would
>   be retained if it did). A clustered database is comprised of several
>   shards, though (the 'q' value, defaulting to 4 iirc). The clustered
>   changes feed combines those separate changes feed into a single one,
>   but makes no effort to impose a total order over that. We don't do it
>   because it would be expensive and unnecessary.

**The solution if you need to listen on a _changes feed and then restart
from where you left off later:**

> The algorithm for correctly consuming the changes feed is:
>
> 1. read /dbname/_changes
> 2. process each row idempotently
> 3. periodically (every X seconds or every X rows) store the "seq" value of the last row you processed
>
> If you ever crash, or if you weren't using continuous=true, you can do
>   this same procedure again but modified in step 1;
>
> revised 1. read /dbname/_changes?since=X
>
> where X is the value you saved in step 3. If you're not using
>   continuous mode then you could just record the "last_seq" value at the
>   end of consuming the non-continuous response. You run the risk of
>   reprocessing a lot more items, though.
>
> With this scheme (which the replicator and all indexers follow), you
>   don't care if the results come out of order, you don't need to compare
>   any two seq values.
>
> You *do* need to ensure you can correctly process the same change
>   multiple times. For an example of that, consider the replicator, when
>   it sees a row from a changes feed it asks the target database if it
>   contains the _id and _rev values from that row. If it does, the
>   replicator moves on to the next row. If it doesn't, it tries to write
>   the document in that row to the target database. In the event of a
>   crash, and therefore a call to _changes with a seq value from before
>   processing that row, it will ask the target database if it has the
>   _id/_rev again, only this time the target will say yes.